# What am I missing for my remote RMI call?

Tags: java, jboss, rmi

What am I missing?
I am trying to make a remote RMI call from a standalone java app to a server-app-ear deployed in a Jboss 6.4 EAP.
(I start the Jboss with standalone-full.xml)

In my server I get this logging during start:

```
07:47:56,928 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
07:47:57,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-6) JNDI bindings for session bean named JournalCrudFacadeBean in deployment unit subdeployment "se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" are as follows:

java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface
java:app/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface
java:module/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface
java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean
java:app/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean
java:module/JournalCrudFacadeBean
```

To me that sounds like I should be able to "look up" the JournalCrudFacadeBean using one of these "names", probably "global", right? I guess "app" is useful within the same app, and "module" within the same module, right? So global sounds more like it.

I also have add a application user in the server, "testapplication".

A snippet from JournalCrudFacadeBean looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class JournalCrudFacadeBean implements JournalCrudRemoteInterface {

    public String create(Date date) throws RemoteException 
    {   
        String id = "A id"
        System.out.println( id );
        return id;
    }
```

And a snippet from the interface looks like:

```
public interface JournalCrudRemoteInterface extends Remote
{
    public String create(Date date) throws RemoteException;
```

In my standalone app I make the call like:

```
private String create() 
{
    String id = "Inget svar";
    try 
    {
        final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        //jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");

        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remoting://localhost:4447");
        
        jndiProperties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "testapplication");
        jndiProperties.put("remote.connection.default.password", "!234qwer");
        
                    
        final InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext( jndiProperties );

        JournalCrudRemoteInterface journalCrudRemoteInterface = (JournalCrudRemoteInterface) ctx.lookup( "java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface" );
        //JournalCrudRemoteInterface journalCrudRemoteInterface = (JournalCrudRemoteInterface) ctx.lookup( "java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean" );
        id = journalCrudRemoteInterface.create(new Date());
        System.out.println(id);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        id = e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } 
    finally 
    {
    }

    return id;
}
```

In the client I got these dependencies:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ rmi-client ---
[INFO] se.testcompany.testapplication:rmi-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.wildfly:wildfly-naming-client:jar:1.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.client:wildfly-client-config:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.5.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.5.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- se.testcompany.testapplication:rmi-interface:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

But when I call it I get:

```
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.0.Final
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
```

What do you think guys, do you see where I am doing it wrong?
Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

Check if your lookup name is correct. You can check it from your Jboss's admin console-> runtime tab -> JNDI view. Is there a JNDI with your lookup

```
java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, in my server.log I get: java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface. So it looks correct! But unfortunately I get the NameNotFoundException.

Comment: Hello, and in the console I also can see: java:global/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/se.testcompany.testapplication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JournalCrudFacadeBean!se.testcompany.testapplication.rmi_interface.JournalCrudRemoteInterface

Comment: I also tried telnet: telnet localhost 4447
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

 localhost
...seems like there is no firewall in the way to me, right?

Comment: @user2902165 It's not a connectviity problem. Read the exception. It's a naming problem. The service hasn't bound itself under that name in that naming service. Either you're looking up the wrong naming service or you're using the wrong name within it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, so what you are saying is that I must be connected to some naming service, else I should get some other Exception, right? Or I am connected to the right naming service, but in some strange way the service/bean is not possible accessible under the name that is printed out in the server.log and in the console, right? Do you guys know any way to see if I am connected to the correct naming service? (I am thinking of change the url or the user-name or something, it would be great to see any log on the server just to know client and server is connected). Best regards Fred

Comment: No it isn't right. Just read what I wrote. I'm not going to play the 'so what you are saying is ...' game. I've already said it. You don't need to mangle my concise and clear explanation into your own incomprehensible syntax and then ask me to agree with it. I don't. It's pointless. Lose this bad habit.